# How to line up two tables in html?

Tags: html, css

I Want both tables To be aligned at the top along the bottom of the header on my website. How can I have both Tables aligned to the top? Currently one table is in the top left corner(correct spot) and the other is centered on the page but underneath the other table. How can I raise the table to be in line with the other table?

Wesite at `http://108.210.72.235/docs/`
or
[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ejnd2.png)

```
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" COLS="4" BORDER="0" style="margin:65px 0px 0px 70px;">
    <COLGROUP SPAN="4" WIDTH="85"></COLGROUP>
    <TR>
        <TD BGCOLOR="#D7D7D7" style="font-family: DejaVu, serif;font-size: 150%;HEIGHT="18" ALIGN="LEFT"><A HREF="/docs" style="text-decoration: none;">Documents</A></TD>

    <TR>
        <TD BGCOLOR="#DD8D8"style="font-family: DejaVu, serif;font-size: 150%;HEIGHT="18" ALIGN="LEFT"><A HREF="/erm" style="text-decoration: none;">Erm?</A></TD>
        <TD ALIGN="LEFT"><BR></TD>
    <TR>
        <TD BGCOLOR="#D8D8D8"style="font-family: DejaVu, serif;font-size: 150%;HEIGHT="18" ALIGN="LEFT"><A HREF="/music" style="text-decoration: none;">Music</A></TD>
        <TD ALIGN="LEFT"><BR></TD>


</TABLE>
<TABLE VALIGN=CENTER ALIGN=CENTER>
<?php
 if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
   while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
      {
          if ($file != "." && $file != "..")
      {
            $thelist .= '   <TR>
        <TD BGCOLOR="#D8D8D8" style="font-family: DejaVu, serif;font-size: 150%;HEIGHT="18" ALIGN="LEFT"><a href="'. $file.'">' .$file. '</a></TD>
        <TD ALIGN="LEFT"><BR></TD>';
          }
       }
  closedir($handle);
  }
?>
<P><?=$thelist?></p>
</TABLE>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `float:left` to the left-hand table's style.

```
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" COLS="4" BORDER="0" style="margin:65px 0px 0px 70px;float:left">
```

Answer (score 0):

Tables are block elements and so will never sit next to another block (following the normal flow of the page) changing the table's style in one of the following ways should get the effect you are looking for:

```
float:left;

display:inline-block;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the second table to be displayed on the left, under the first table just remove the `valign` and `align` properties from your second table.

If you want the second table do be displayed under your header, on the right side of your first table add the following code to the `style` attribute of your first table `float:left;`

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
<table border="1" width="100%">  
  <tr>  
    <td width="20%>  
      Insert table 1 here  
    </td>  
    <td width="80%>  
      Insert table 2 here  
    </td>  
  </tr>  
</table>
```